# Make ajax call only on particular page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a multi-page app, with several pages making ajax requests. **I want to make sure that each request is fired on a specific page (rather than every page).**

For example the following will make a call on every page in my express app:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('/api/skills/user')
    .then(selected => {
      console.log("js.2. pre-populate GET /api/skills/user/")
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("$.getJSON('/api/skills/user/') failed")
    })
}
```

I am attempting to only make this call on a particular page by first checking if a string matches the URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(window.location.toString().includes("profile")) {

    $.getJSON('/api/skills/user')
      .then(selected => {
        console.log("js.2. pre-populate GET /api/skills/user/")
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("$.getJSON('/api/skills/user/') failed")
      })
  }
}
```

However, if I want to make this call on pages with URLs like `/profile/...` but not `profile/.../matches/...` this approach does not work (as it finds `profile` in both `/profile/...` and `profile/.../matches/...`).

How should I go about doing this? I could check the URL against a regex, but it doesn't seem like a particularly good way of doing this.

**Is there a standard way of making an ajax call in a page-specific fashion?**

Comment: You could use a regular expression to ensure that the string also _doesn't_ contain anything after a certain point, or doesn't contain certain other words. Seems reasonable - why don't you like that idea? But also, how about just moving this code to a JS file, and only including the JS file on pages which actually need it?

Comment: As mentioned in comment above: the standard way to have code only run on a single page is to have that code in a .js file and only include it on the pages you want it to run on.

Comment: That's a nice idea re: sourcing scripts on a per-page basis. I'm currently sourcing all `.js` files together in a `partials/footer`

Comment: @fugu Try to avoid loading unused JS to your page. I would handle that on backend, and load the appropriate JS file depending the location.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sourcing scripts per-page is what I'll do.

Comment: On the converse, modern browsers are very good at caching *post-parsed* scripts - so if you have some scripts that are used on many pages, then it's ok to include them - you get a slightly slower startup but quicker pages after the first.  So depends on how your site is used - a typical webuser site doesn't want this, but a typical business app might take advantage.  If you bundle, then don't bundle per page as that's the worse of both options (bundle most, then per-page the small, specific, per-page requirement).

Comment: @freedomn-m - ps this might make a good answer, if expanded a bit.